# How to I get the right output when there is more than vowel in each word? My code only works with one vowel in each word

Tags: ruby

Aba is a German children’s game where secret messages are exchanged. In Aba,
after every vowel we add “b” and add that same vowel.
Write a method `aba_translate` that takes in a sentence string and returns a new
sentence representing its Aba translation. Capitalized words of the original sentence
should be properly capitalized in the new sentence.

```
aba_translate(“Cats and dogs”) #=> “Cabats aband dobogs”

aba_translate(“Everyone can code”) #=> “Ebeveryobonebe caban cobodebe”

aba_translate(“Africa is Africa in German”) #=> “Abafribicaba ibis Abafribicaba ibin
Gebermaban”
```

My code:

```
def aba_translate(sentence)

  translation = []
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  vowels = "aeiou"
  vowel = ""
  before = ""
  after = ""
  full = ""
  
  words.each do |word|

    word.each_char.with_index do |char, idx|

      if vowels.include?(char)
          vowel = char
          before = word[0...idx]
          after = word[idx+1..-1]

          full = before + vowel + "b" + vowel + after
          translation << full
      end

    end

  end

  return translation.join(" ")

end

puts aba_translate("Cats and dogs")
puts aba_translate("Everyone can code") 
puts aba_translate("Africa is Africa in German")
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Please show your code and error/s. My guess is that something is stopping when a vowel is reached rather than until the end of the string.

Comment: I just added it sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generates a whole new word every time it sees a vowel. Instead you need to build each word character by character and make changes when it sees a vowel.

```
def aba_translate(sentence)

  translation = []
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

  words.each do |word|
    full = ""
    word.each_char.with_index do |char, idx|
      full += char
      if vowels.include?(char)
          full = full + "b" + char.downcase
      end
    end
    translation << full
  end

  return translation.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you find a vowel, you take the *entire string* before the vowel and the *entire string* after the vowel and add it to the result.

So, for a word like "code", that means you first produce the output `c` + `obo` + `de` and then the output `cod` + `ebe`.

However, what you actually need to do is simply *keep* the part you have processed instead of *duplicating* it.

You can do this by either changing your logic to keep track of up to which index you have already processed the word, or alternatively by processing it character-by-character instead of chunk-by-chunk.

However for problems like this, `Regex` are usually a much better solution:

```ruby
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

def aba_translate(sentence)
  sentence.gsub(Regexp.union(*VOWELS.chars), '\0b\0')
end
```

or just making `VOWELS` a `Regexp` in the first place:

```ruby
VOWELS = /[aeiou]/.freeze

def aba_translate(sentence)
  sentence.gsub(VOWELS, '\0b\0')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the nested loops complicates it since you can solve the problem with just one loop. Here you just need to initialize a string and a string of vowels to check each character. While you iterate through each character you shovel it into the empty string, and then you check if it is a vowel you shovel b + that vowel's lowercase version to account for the uppercase instances. Then you finally return the new string.

```
def aba_translate(string)

    new_string = ""
    vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"

    string.each_char do |char|
       new_string << char
       if vowels.include?(char)
       new_string << "b" + char.downcase
       end
    end
return new_string
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my beginner-friendly solution

```
def aba_translate(sent)
vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"

aba_sent = ""
sent.each_char do |char|
    if vowels.include?(char)
        aba_sent += char + "b" + char.downcase
    else 
        aba_sent += char
    end
end

return aba_sent
```

end